# API response taking too long from real device

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have developed an android app which has APIs in PHP. The APIs are taking too long to respond when I run the app on real device and that too in release mode with debugging off. When I try to hit the same APIs from postman, it takes about 1183 ms. However, the release version of the app works the way faster in emulator and this slow response issue is not observed there. I tried following things to resolve this issue:

1. Changing base URL from subdomain (subdomain.domain.com) to domain name (domain.com/subdomain)
2. Running app in release mode with `debuggable = false` in gradle
3. adding `okhttpClient` in retrofit builder explicitly
4. Creating .apk and then installing it on my device
5. also tried installing same on another device as well

but still it didn't work. Also, tried the solutions from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35478568/retrofit-slower-response-time-in-real-android-devices-when-compared-to-emulator) but no of the answer solved this issue. Any suggestion will be very helpful.

Comment: If the API is taking too much time this is a server problem and not a client problem. You should redirect your app traffic through a proxy like mitmproxy and look carefully at the requests sent. Most likely they contain something unexpected that causes the server to spend too much time.

Comment: @Robert but that didn't affect postman, only taking time from real device. Postman request is pretty fast

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77714446/android-httpsurlconnection-is-very-slow-to-return-502-bad-gateway/77717753?noredirect=1

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution after talking to my hosting service agents. They recommended to transfer the server to the nearest location and it did the trick for me. Now the APIs are loading faster. Hope this helps who is going through the same problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).